# How to use GPU to parallelize in C++ using openmp

Tags: c++

I have a question about CPU and GPU.

Currently, I am using Openmp to parallelize my code in C++. (Visual studio)

The maximum thread I get is 12.

But I need to make this code faster. So I am thinking of changing my desktop.

I am not familiar with all these computer equipments so I have few questions about them.

I guess the reason why I am having 12 threads is that my CPU (i7) has 6 cores so I think I am using CPU to parallelize my code.

1.So my first question is can I use GPU rather than CPU?

2.I guess the number of the core is important in CPU parallelization and the number of cuda cores is important in GPU parallelization. Am I right?

3.If there is a way to use GPU to parallelize and if I could upgrade my graphic card, can I use more threads so that I can make my code faster?

Below is a part of my code. I used #pragma omp parallel for private for CPU parallelization and I thought #pragma omp target... is for GPU parallelization but it doesn't work...

```
//#pragma omp parallel for private(Val)     
#pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for private(Val)     
for (int a = 0; a < Na; a++) {
    for (int b = 0; b < Nd; b++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < Ny; c++) {
            max = -99999;
            for (int d = 0; d < Na; d++) {
                for (int e = 0; e < Nd; e++) {
                    Val[d][e] = Uvec[a][b][c][d][e] + Vfuture[d][e];
                    if (max < Val[d][e]) {
                        max = Val[d][e];
                        maxposition_a[a][b][c] = d;
                        maxposition_d[a][b][c] = e;
                    }
                }
            }
            Vnew[a][b][c] = max;
        }
    }
}
```